# What is the torque produced by 2 rotating bodies with a clutch

Tags: rotational-dynamics, momentum, torque

I am trying to simulate a car engine etc, but I have failed to find any equations governing the torque created by $2$ different constant velocity shafts of different angular momenta joining together with some given slip or friction factor. I know $I_1w1 + I_2w_2 = I_3w_3$ which gives me the end angular velocities, but its not giving me the torque acting on each shaft at any moment in time whilst they are joining.

Answer (score 1):

A clutch has two sides and a degree of freedom between them. Let's call one side the engine side with known torque $\tau_E$ and unknown speed $\omega_E$. On the other side, the transmission side, the speed is known $\omega_T$, but the transmitted torque $\tau_T$ isn't.

The clutch itself has a critical torque $\tau_C$ which limits its ability to transfer torque. This limits, depends on the engagement of the clutch, and it varies between zero and some maximum value that is *more* than the maximum the engine can supply $\tau_{C_{\rm max}} >\tau_{E_{\rm max}}$.

So value of the maximum critical torque (torque rating) does not matter for the operation of the car. All it matters is that with 100% clutch in $\tau_C = 0$ and with 0% clutch in $\tau_C > \tau_{E_{\rm max}}$.

---

Here is a system diagram that will drive the equations

[image: System Diagram]

The components are shown in boxes, and the system variables connect the components.

First, the kinematics are valid regardless of how the clutch behaves

$$ \begin{aligned}
   \omega_W & = \frac{v}{R} & \dot \omega_W & = \frac{\dot v}{R} \\
   \omega_T & = \gamma\; \omega_W &  \dot \omega_T & = \gamma\; \dot \omega_W
\end{aligned} \tag{1} $$
<sub>Where $gamma$ is the total gear ratio, and $R$ the wheel radius.</sub>

And thus the engine torque is always known if the engine speed $\omega_E$ is known $$ \tau_E = f(\omega_E) \tag{2}$$

Considering that each component has each own mass moment of inertia, as well as the combined mass of the car $m$ and any drag force $F_D$ applied, the equations of motion for the car, wheel and transmission are:

$$ \begin{aligned}
 F  & = m \dot v + F_D \\
 \tau_W &= I_W \dot \omega_W + F\,R \\
 \tau_T &= I_T \dot \omega_T + \tfrac{1}{\gamma} \tau_W
\end{aligned} \tag{3}$$

Notice that all the accelerations can be written in terms of $\dot v$, such as $\dot \omega_W = \tfrac{1}{R} \dot v$ and $\dot \omega_T = \tfrac{\gamma}{R} \dot v$.

Then the two scenarios for the clutch:

- **Clutch engaged** - engine speed matches transmission speed, $\omega_E = \omega_T$ as well as $\dot \omega_E = \dot \omega_T$

$$ \begin{aligned} \tau_E &= \tau_C + I_E \dot \omega_T \\
  \tau_C & = I_C \dot \omega_T + \tau_T \end{aligned} \\ \tag{4a} $$

The above 5 equations in (3) & (4a) are solved for $\tau_C$, $\tau_T$, $\tau_W$, $F$ and finally $\dot{v}$

Notice that the engine speed is directly linked to the car speed $\omega_E = \omega_T = \tfrac{\gamma}{R} v $ and so engine torque is known $\tau_E = f(\omega_E)$.

- **Clutch slipping** - transmission torque limited to $\tau_C$

$$ \begin{aligned} \tau_E &= \tau_C + I_E \dot \omega_E \\
  \tau_C & = I_C \dot \omega_T + \tau_T \end{aligned} \tag{4b} $$

The above 5 equations in (3) & (4b) are solved for $\omega_E$, $\tau_T$ $\tau_W$, $F$ and finally $\dot{v}$

Here the engine speed is found from the numeric integral $\Delta \omega_E = \int \dot \omega_E \,{\rm d}t $ and the car acceleration $\dot v$ does not depend on engine torque.

The conditions of slipping the clutch are $\tau_E > \tau_C$, and for engaging the clutch $| \omega_E - \omega_T | \approx 0$.

Comment: So you are saying the clutch acts like a torque limiter. With your last equation if the Torque of the engine is say 300 and the clutch torque is say 50 then the accel of the engine would be (300+50)/I engine. Is this right that the clutch torque is added to the engine torque ?

Comment: Also I am still unsure of how to calculate the accel and therefore the rpm of the engine as affected by the angular momentum from the weight of the car whilst the clutch is slipping ( the original question).So when I change gear, the engine speed will broadly go to the road speed combined with the gear ratio. So I can sort of see when  I bring the clutch together  Torque Car = Inertia car.(w combined- w separated)/time to join. I can see the Torque transferred to the engine from the wheels could be limited by torque clutch, but I dont know the Torque and I dont know the clutch join time!

Comment: Torque flows from the engine to the wheels, not the other way around.

Comment: @MajorTom - So, I made some changes to the post. You have to consider the clutch and engine as a system. The difference between engaged clutch and slipping clutch is that in the first case motion is known and torque out calculated, and in the second base torque is known and motion is calculated.

Comment: Ja thank you very much for your help, I am still trying to wrap my brain around the equations and quite what they mean. I would say when the clutch is slipping, the acceleration of the car does depend on the engine torque, though not if is equal or above Tc. Is this the on the Tc limit case rather than that the general case of when the Engine is producing less Torque than the clutch can handle any given clutch position?  In short I need to know how to calculate engine rpm at any given clutch position to calculate the engine torque. The omega e equation. Im probably staring at it but cant see

Comment: The mathworks link Eli provided appears to have some key equations I think I have been missing. So there is a Tfmaxk which = two thirds RFnuk. Where R is equiv radius of clutch, Fn is force pushing clutch together uk is dynamic friction of clutch, and Tfmaxk is max dynamic friction transmitable by clutch.  Tclutch is the torque transmitted through the clutch, so Tclutch = sign(we-wt)Tfmaxk,  where we and wt are angular velocities of engine and other side of clutch.I think this is the answer to my original question. I think this along with your 4b equations are what I needed.

Comment: My thesis is that the limiting torque value does not matter unless you are planning to have the clutch slip while fully engaged. That does not happen in regular cars.

Comment: Ok so I think your Tclutch is their Tfmax and your Tt (Torque transmitted is their T clutch). I think this was what was confusing me ! For what its worth they have different Fmaxs for their static joined and dynamic (slipping ) clutch Fmax values.Though I think you should add the Tt = (we-wt)Tc equation to your answer (from the mathworks link) (assuming you agree with it !) I know a simulation is only as good as its model and I dont know if that equation is correct or some crude apporximation !

Answer (score 0):

In a system with two drive shafts connected by a clutch and a system of gears, the power being transmitted by each shaft will be the torque times the angular velocity. (The angular momentum of each shaft is not of concern.)  The ratio of the two angular velocities is determined by the system of gears. The clutch allows the second shaft to start at rest and be brought up to speed.  In bringing the second shaft up to speed, some energy will be lost to friction in the clutch, and some will be needed to increase the kinetic energy of the second shaft and the gears.  After that, (if you have friction-less bearings and gears) all of the power supplied to the first shaft should emerge from the second shaft.

Comment: So I am still a bit confused by all this and will cut to the chase  and ask how do you calculate the rpm drop of the engine each frame of the simulation given some percentage that the clutch is engaged, assuming that the amount the clutch is engaged and the throttle (hence torque)  can vary during the clutch engagement.

Comment: Still a bit confused, so I  ask how do you calculate the rpm drop of the engine each frame of the simulation given some percentage that the clutch is engaged, assuming that the amount the clutch is engaged and the throttle (hence torque)  can vary during the clutch engagement. From what you say it sounds like assuming a car rolling along in a vacuum that changes gear, the rolling car itself will create no torque, but the torque created by the engine will be reflected back on itself and will be what slows the revs down. How long will the clutch engagement last for a given clutch say 20 percent.

Comment: These days the function of the clutch is performed by the automatic transmission.  As you ramp up the power, the transmission smoothly applies that torque to the drive train.  A lifetime ago it took practice to learn how to coordinate the engine power with the slow release of the clutch, which might take two or three seconds. The percentage of engagement of the clutch increased over that period of time.  The torque and power supplied to the wheels increases over that period and continues to increase as the engine speeds up.  In a simulation, you get to play with all the variables in a system.

Answer (score 0):

> I can see the Torque transferred to the engine from the wheels could be limited by torque clutch, but I dont know the Torque and I dont know the clutch join time!

Correct.  You need to make assumptions.  If you have an inexperienced driver that releases the clutch instantly, the maximum torque that can be applied may well exceed stress limits on parts.  The theoretical maximum depends on the specifics of the clutch.  The faster it engages, the greater the maximum torque can be.

It's like asking the force on an object that bounces.  It depends on the materials.  A soft ball on a piece of foam will have low force.  Two steel balls bouncing might have forces of several thousand newtons.  But the total momentum change might be identical.  The only difference is the time involved.

An automatic transmission's torque converter, or an experienced manual driver will manipulate things in a way to limit the total torque.  But this is a variable, not something that falls out of your equations.